# xml string to file

Tags: java, xml

I want a xml string to be converted to file,for which i am doing in the below way,

```
String xmlFile=responseXMLName;
log.info("xml file :" +xmlFile);
fr = new FileWriter(new File(xmlFile));
Writer br= new BufferedWriter(fr); 
log.info("respose string"+responseXMLString);
br.write(responseXMLString);
br.close();
```

i want to pass xml file data to this function ,how would i do this?

```
Document doc = builder.build(...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader( s );
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( reader );
Document doc = builder.parse( inputSource );
reader.close();
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a file:

```
FileWriter fr = null;
try {
  String xmlFile=responseXMLName;
  log.info("xml file :" +xmlFile);
  fr = new FileWriter(xmlFile);
  log.info("respose string"+responseXMLString);
  fr.write(responseXMLString);
} finally {
  if (fr != null) {
      fr.close();
  }
}
```

To get the document:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader( responseXMLString );
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( reader );
Document doc = builder.parse( inputSource );
reader.close();
```